# how does croot work in android? Additionally, how do I replicate this functionality inside a python script?

Tags: android, python, git, gerrit

I would like to find the path of a repository given its name in an Android build environment.

Currently this is how I do it:

- croot (Maybe croot source can help me get a clue to implement this in python?)
- vi .repo/manifest.xml
- grep for repository name and find its corresponding path
- cd repository path

I want to achieve these steps with a python script. 
The requirement is to be able to do this from anywhere inside an android build system given the name of the project (which I obtain from the Gerrit I would like to cherry-pick or pull).

This command would result in taking me to the project directory.

> ./test.py project_name

Any ideas or alternate methods to achieve this would be helpful too.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this did the trick!

```
import sys
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main():
    project_name=str(sys.argv[1])
    top_dir=os.environ['ANDROID_BUILD_TOP']       # There is a global variable that is set
                                                  # that will help you do croot while 
                                                  # running in python shell.
    manifest_file='.repo/manifests.xml'

    os.chdir(top_dir)
    tree = ET.parse(manifest_file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for project in root.findall('project'):
        if (project_name == project.get('name')):
            print project.get('path')
            exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The only problem is I cannot cd to the project path directly since you are not able to change the directory of the parent on exit. I can live with that I guess.